# AutoHotKey, Uptading Icons

Tags: menu, icons, autohotkey

So i have a problem with updating the icon for my gui. I want to have it so when i press a button the icon changes, and when i press another button it changes to a different icon.

I can change the icon once when i create the gui with this script:

```
gui, show, w0 h0
Menu, Tray, Icon, %A_WorkingDir%\Files\Red_Icon.ico, 1, 1
gui, destroy
```

But i cant seem to be able to change it multiple times without restartin the window

So im wondering how i change the icon multiple times/How to uppdate to icon

Also, Im talking about both the icon on the taskbar!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/122770-how-to-change-the-icon-on-a-taskbar-button/)'s a stab at changing the taskbar icon, but you'll soon face an inherent limitation as discussed in the same thread and another referred to in it.

There's also a [workaround](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/122831-a-basic-problem-with-program-icons-under-windows/?p=692316), which, however, I find too drastic.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar questions were just asked and answered here:

[Change autohotkey tray icon from within script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967404/change-autohotkey-tray-icon-from-within-script)

[AutoHotKey, Updating Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49803867/autohotkey-updating-icons)

These should give you a head start on correcting your issue.